# strange query in server logs REMOTE HI_SRDK_DEV_GetHddInfo

Tags: http

I have this http request in my server logs:

REMOTE HI_SRDK_DEV_GetHddInfo

Has anyone seen this message before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like somebody using exploit to find and hack Kguard Digital Video Recorders in the internet. Ignore if you don't have one.

https://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/1506-exploits/kdvr-authorization.txt

Answer (score 0):

[HiSilicon](http://www.hisilicon.com/)  provides SDK for developing digital video recorders and web cameras software.  SDK contains protocol for remote device configuration named "MCTP". Сommands transmitted by this protocol have names similar to **HI_SRDK_SYS_USERMNG_GetUserList, HI_SRDK_NET_GetEmailAttr**, etc. Someone wanted to find a HiSilicon based video recorder on your IP address, possibly for hacking.